# Tableau to R: Call an R function from Tableau without return type

Tags: r, tableau-api

As I read and understood, we can only receive following four variables as return type when we call R from Tableau :
SCRIPT_REAL, SCRIPT_INT, SCRIPT_BOOL and SCRIPT_REAL after connecting to Rserve.

But I want a dataframe as return from R. I browsed through a few links where one of the solutions was to write the dataframe to hard drive and
read it from Tableau next. What code should I write in Tableau to accomplish this task?

Here is the sample R function I want to execute:

```
write_csv <- function(perc)
{
  ### Create dataframe
  employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
  salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
  
  ### Calc field 
  data <- data.frame(employee, salary)
  data$SpendAmt <- data$salary*(perc/100)
  
  #### Write Dataframe
  write.csv(data,"Sample_Test.csv")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution is not about tableau functions. It is nothing but assigning the csv path to the Tableau. After writing your csv file in `R` by `write.csv()`, just upload your file in Tableau via the screen shown at the opening as usual like uploading an excel to the Tableau. Then arrange a refreshing period to tell the Tableau to reload the csv file you have created periodically. If I am not wrong, Tableau just takes a vector from `Rserve` and does not permit a dataframe! It is a huge weakness of Tableau!

Comment: maydin , thanks for comments. I was curious to know how we can call an R function from Tableau where there is no return type expected. As such Tableau can receive one of the 4 types mentioned above, I used SCRIPT_REAL as return type and in R, wrote return(1.1) in last line. Not sure there is w a better way to do it.

Comment: Now, I created a workaround like how you said, say write CSV after calculation and have a read connection to Tableau next. However, the problem is data doesnt get updated unless I click REFRESH in 'Data Source' tab. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: If you want to publish your workbook, in Tableau Server, you can assign a refresh period for the data. But in Tableau Desktop, I am not sure.